Postfix: Mail servers of certain providers are unable to send mail to my Postfix server / insufficient security / SSL alert number 71
There is big German email hoster (web.de) whose mail servers are not able to send mails to my self-hosted Postfix server. I found similar reports, but the published solutions always were misconfigured TLSA records. However, I am sure that my TLSA record is fine.
How do I fix the problem such that my Postfix server receives mails from those servers correctly?

Postfix version: 3.8.5
OpenSSL version: 3.0.13-r2

My Postfix logs:
May 08 12:05:37 server postfix/smtpd[90259]: initializing the server-side TLS engine
May 08 12:05:37 server postfix/smtpd[90259]: connect from mout.web.de[212.227.15.4]
May 08 12:05:38 server postfix/smtpd[90259]: setting up TLS connection from mout.web.de[212.227.15.4]
May 08 12:05:38 server postfix/smtpd[90259]: mout.web.de[212.227.15.4]: TLS cipher list "aNULL:-aNULL:HIGH:MEDIUM:!SEED:!IDEA:!3DES:!RC2:!RC4:!RC5:!kDH:!kECDH:!aDSS:!MD5:+RC4:@STRENGTH"
May 08 12:05:38 server postfix/smtpd[90259]: SSL_accept:before SSL initialization
May 08 12:05:38 server postfix/smtpd[90259]: SSL_accept:before SSL initialization
May 08 12:05:38 server postfix/smtpd[90259]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS read client hello
May 08 12:05:38 server postfix/smtpd[90259]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS write server hello
May 08 12:05:38 server postfix/smtpd[90259]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS write change cipher spec
May 08 12:05:38 server postfix/smtpd[90259]: SSL_accept:TLSv1.3 write encrypted extensions
May 08 12:05:38 server postfix/smtpd[90259]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS write certificate
May 08 12:05:38 server postfix/smtpd[90259]: SSL_accept:TLSv1.3 write server certificate verify
May 08 12:05:38 server postfix/smtpd[90259]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS write finished
May 08 12:05:38 server postfix/smtpd[90259]: SSL_accept:TLSv1.3 early data
May 08 12:05:38 server postfix/smtpd[90259]: SSL_accept:TLSv1.3 early data
May 08 12:05:38 server postfix/smtpd[90259]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS read finished
May 08 12:05:38 server postfix/smtpd[90259]: mout.web.de[212.227.15.4]: Issuing session ticket, key expiration: 1715164537
May 08 12:05:38 server postfix/smtpd[90259]: SSL_accept:SSLv3/TLS write session ticket
May 08 12:05:38 server postfix/smtpd[90259]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mout.web.de[212.227.15.4]: TLSv1.3 with cipher TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (256/256 bits) key-exchange ECDHE (prime256v1) server-signature RSA-PSS (2048 bits) server-digest SHA256
May 08 12:05:38 server postfix/smtpd[90259]: SSL3 alert read:fatal:insufficient security
May 08 12:05:38 server postfix/smtpd[90259]: warning: TLS library problem: error:0A00042F:SSL routines::tlsv1 alert insufficient security:../openssl-3.0.13/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1590:SSL alert number 71:
May 08 12:05:38 server postfix/smtpd[90259]: lost connection after STARTTLS from mout.web.de[212.227.15.4]
May 08 12:05:38 server postfix/smtpd[90259]: disconnect from mout.web.de[212.227.15.4] ehlo=1 starttls=1 commands=2
May

I am not sure which side is reporting "insufficient security". My own side, i.e. Postfix/TLS server? Or the remote side, i.e. the web.de mail server which is the TLS client?
My server provides two Letsencrypt certificates:

one EC certificate,
one RSA certificate.

The relevant TLS directives from my Postfix main.cf:
# TLS PARAMETERS
#

smtpd_tls_chain_files =
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.my-domain.tld:smtps-ec/privkey.pem,
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.my-domain.tld:smtps-ec/fullchain.pem,
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.my-domain.tld:smtps-rsa/privkey.pem,
  /etc/letsencrypt/live/server.my-domain.tld:smtps-rsa/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_CApath              = /etc/ssl/certs
# note: for port 587, smtpd_tls_security_level is overwritten to `encrypt` in master.cf
smtpd_tls_security_level      = may
smtpd_tls_received_header     = yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only           = yes
smtpd_tls_ciphers             = medium
smtpd_tls_protocols           = >=TLSv1.2
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers   = high
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = >=TLSv1.2
smtpd_tls_loglevel            = 0

smtp_tls_CApath              = /etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level      = may
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_ciphers             = medium
smtp_tls_protocols           = >=TLSv1.2
smtp_tls_mandatory_ciphers   = high
smtp_tls_mandatory_protocols = >=TLSv1.2
smtp_tls_loglevel            = 0

In both cases, the trust anchor is "ISRG Root X1". My TLSA record is
$ dig TLSA _25._tcp.server.my-domain.tld.
_25._tcp.server.my-domain.tld.   12340 IN   CNAME   letsencrypt._dane.my-domain.tld.
letsencrypt._dane.my-domain.tld. 13104 IN   TLSA    0 1 1 0B9FA5A59EED715C26C1020C711B4F6EC42D58B0015E14337A39DAD3 01C5AFC3

Running SSL Scan against my own Postfix server yields:
# sslscan --verbose --starttls-smtp server.my-domain.tld:25
Version: 2.1.2-static
OpenSSL 3.0.12 24 Oct 2023

Some servers will fail to response to SSLv3 ciphers over STARTTLS
If your scan hangs, try using the --tlsall option

Testing SSL server server.my-domain.tld on port 25 using SNI name server.my-domain.tld

  SSL/TLS Protocols:
SSLv2     disabled
SSLv3     disabled
TLSv1.0   disabled
TLSv1.1   disabled
TLSv1.2   enabled
TLSv1.3   enabled

  TLS Fallback SCSV:
OpenSSL OpenSSL 3.0.12 24 Oct 2023 looks like version 0.9.8m or later; I will try SSL_OP to enable renegotiation
OpenSSL OpenSSL 3.0.12 24 Oct 2023 looks like version 0.9.8m or later; I will try SSL_OP to enable renegotiation
Server supports TLS Fallback SCSV

  TLS renegotiation:
OpenSSL OpenSSL 3.0.12 24 Oct 2023 looks like version 0.9.8m or later; I will try SSL_OP to enable renegotiation
use_unsafe_renegotiation_op
Session renegotiation not supported

  TLS Compression:
OpenSSL OpenSSL 3.0.12 24 Oct 2023 looks like version 0.9.8m or later; I will try SSL_OP to enable renegotiation
Compression disabled

  Heartbleed:
TLSv1.3 not vulnerable to heartbleed
TLSv1.2 not vulnerable to heartbleed

  Supported Server Cipher(s):
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Preferred TLSv1.3  128 bits  TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256        Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.3  256 bits  TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384        Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.3  256 bits  TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256  Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: -1
SSL_get_current_cipher() returned NULL; this indicates that the server did not choose a cipher from our list (TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_CCM_8_SHA256)
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Preferred TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384   Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384     DHE 2048 bits
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305 Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305   Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305     DHE 2048 bits
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-CCM8       Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-CCM        Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-CCM8           DHE 2048 bits
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-CCM            DHE 2048 bits
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-ARIA256-GCM-SHA384 Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-ARIA256-GCM-SHA384      Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  DHE-RSA-ARIA256-GCM-SHA384    DHE 2048 bits
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ADH-AES256-GCM-SHA384         DHE 3072 bits
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256   Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256     DHE 2048 bits
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-CCM8       Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-CCM        Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-CCM8           DHE 2048 bits
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-CCM            DHE 2048 bits
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-ARIA128-GCM-SHA256 Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-ARIA128-GCM-SHA256      Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  DHE-RSA-ARIA128-GCM-SHA256    DHE 2048 bits
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ADH-AES128-GCM-SHA256         DHE 1024 bits
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384     Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384       Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256         DHE 2048 bits
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA384 Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA384  Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA256    DHE 2048 bits
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ADH-AES256-SHA256             DHE 3072 bits
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ADH-CAMELLIA256-SHA256        DHE 3072 bits
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256     Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256       Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256         DHE 2048 bits
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA256 Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA256  Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA256    DHE 2048 bits
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ADH-AES128-SHA256             DHE 1024 bits
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ADH-CAMELLIA128-SHA256        DHE 1024 bits
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA        Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA          Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA            DHE 2048 bits
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA       DHE 2048 bits
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  AECDH-AES256-SHA              Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ADH-AES256-SHA                DHE 3072 bits
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ADH-CAMELLIA256-SHA           DHE 3072 bits
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA        Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA          Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA            DHE 2048 bits
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA       DHE 2048 bits
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  AECDH-AES128-SHA              Curve 25519 DHE 253
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ADH-AES128-SHA                DHE 1024 bits
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ADH-CAMELLIA128-SHA           DHE 1024 bits
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  AES256-GCM-SHA384            
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  AES256-CCM8                  
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  AES256-CCM                   
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  ARIA256-GCM-SHA384           
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  AES128-GCM-SHA256            
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  AES128-CCM8                  
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  AES128-CCM                   
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  ARIA128-GCM-SHA256           
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  AES256-SHA256                
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  CAMELLIA256-SHA256           
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  AES128-SHA256                
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  CAMELLIA128-SHA256           
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  AES256-SHA                   
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  256 bits  CAMELLIA256-SHA              
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  AES128-SHA                   
SSL_connect() returned: 1
Accepted  TLSv1.2  128 bits  CAMELLIA128-SHA              
SSL_connect() returned: -1
SSL_get_current_cipher() returned NULL; this indicates that the server did not choose a cipher from our list (ALL:COMPLEMENTOFALL:!ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:!ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:!DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:!ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:!ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:!DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:!ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-CCM8:!ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-CCM:!DHE-RSA-AES256-CCM8:!DHE-RSA-AES256-CCM:!ECDHE-ECDSA-ARIA256-GCM-SHA384:!ECDHE-ARIA256-GCM-SHA384:!DHE-RSA-ARIA256-GCM-SHA384:!ADH-AES256-GCM-SHA384:!ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:!ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:!DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:!ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-CCM8:!ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-CCM:!DHE-RSA-AES128-CCM8:!DHE-RSA-AES128-CCM:!ECDHE-ECDSA-ARIA128-GCM-SHA256:!ECDHE-ARIA128-GCM-SHA256:!DHE-RSA-ARIA128-GCM-SHA256:!ADH-AES128-GCM-SHA256:!ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:!ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:!DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:!ECDHE-ECDSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA384:!ECDHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA384:!DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA256:!ADH-AES256-SHA256:!ADH-CAMELLIA256-SHA256:!ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:!ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:!DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:!ECDHE-ECDSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA256:!ECDHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA256:!DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA256:!ADH-AES128-SHA256:!ADH-CAMELLIA128-SHA256:!ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:!ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA256-SHA:!AECDH-AES256-SHA:!ADH-AES256-SHA:!ADH-CAMELLIA256-SHA:!ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:!ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:!DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:!DHE-RSA-CAMELLIA128-SHA:!AECDH-AES128-SHA:!ADH-AES128-SHA:!ADH-CAMELLIA128-SHA:!AES256-GCM-SHA384:!AES256-CCM8:!AES256-CCM:!ARIA256-GCM-SHA384:!AES128-GCM-SHA256:!AES128-CCM8:!AES128-CCM:!ARIA128-GCM-SHA256:!AES256-SHA256:!CAMELLIA256-SHA256:!AES128-SHA256:!CAMELLIA128-SHA256:!AES256-SHA:!CAMELLIA256-SHA:!AES128-SHA:!CAMELLIA128-SHA)

  Server Key Exchange Group(s):
TLSv1.3  128 bits  secp256r1 (NIST P-256)
TLSv1.3  192 bits  secp384r1 (NIST P-384)
TLSv1.3  260 bits  secp521r1 (NIST P-521)
TLSv1.3  128 bits  x25519
TLSv1.3  224 bits  x448
TLSv1.3  112 bits  ffdhe2048
TLSv1.3  128 bits  ffdhe3072
TLSv1.2  128 bits  secp256r1 (NIST P-256)
TLSv1.2  192 bits  secp384r1 (NIST P-384)
TLSv1.2  260 bits  secp521r1 (NIST P-521)
TLSv1.2  128 bits  x25519
TLSv1.2  224 bits  x448

  SSL Certificate:
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
ECC Curve Name:      secp384r1
ECC Key Strength:    192

Subject:  server.my-domain.tld
Altnames: DNS:server.my-domain.tld
Issuer:   R3

Not valid before: Mar 11 19:44:07 2024 GMT
Not valid after:  Jun  9 19:44:06 2024 GMT

Any ideas why the web.de mail server do not send mails to my Postfix server?

Your system is receiving the alert, so it is the peer (web.de) that is dissatisfied with something, but I don't know (or have access to) that system so I can't directly help. PS: your server has two certs, EC(DSA) and RSA, with matching privatekeys, but it provides only one on a given connection. Although as you say all LE certs currently anchor in X1. Unless maybe you have kept and still send LE's now-obsolete 'compatibility' chain with the bridge to DST X3 and that confuses the peer -- but then I would expect to see 45 cert expired, 46 cert unknown, or 48 unknown CA. Good luck.

I found the solution. It seems that web.de (and gmx.de) only supports TLSA certificate usage 2 (DANE-TA) and 3 (DANE-EE), see RFC 6698, sec. 2.1.1. Hence, the TLSA record must be
letsencrypt._dane.my-domain.tld.  <TTL>  IN  TLSA  2 <selector> <match> <value>

or
letsencrypt._dane.my-domain.tld.  <TTL>  IN  TLSA  3 <selector> <match> <value>

RFC 7672, sec. 3.1.1 states the DANE for MTA-to-MTA communication should not use TLSA certificate usage 0 (PKIX-TA) and 1 (PKIX-EE) as it might happen that the referred TA is not trusted (or known) to the remote MTA. Strangely, web.de has installed Letsencrypt "ISRG Root X1" and trusts it as a TA, because web.de is able to establish a TLS connection when I disable TLSA completely. Hence, it seems that web.de explicitly forbids certificate usage 0 or 1.
Due to its longer validity compared to end-entity certificates, I decided to declare Letsencrypt's intermediate certificate "R3" as DANE-TA and added the TLSA record
letsencrypt._dane.my-domain.tld.  <TTL>  IN  TLSA  2 1 1 8D02536C887482BC34FF54E41D2BA659BF85B341A0A20AFADB5813DCFBCF286D

in addition to the already existing TLSA record
letsencrypt._dane.my-domain.tld.  <TTL>  IN  TLSA  0 1 1 0B9FA5A59EED715C26C1020C711B4F6EC42D58B0015E14337A39DAD301C5AFC3

Notes:

Having multiple TLSA records is fine. If at least one TLSA record matches and is valid, the relying party accepts.
If one uses certificate usage 2 (DANE-TA), then the subscriber must send the certificate which is the DANA-TA along the certification path. As in my case that certificate is also a PKIX intermediate, Postfix sends it.

